# Variable Variable Name in C++

Tags: c#, c++, c, arrays, matlab

For C++, consider the following Pseudo-Code:

```
int sampleFunction (int selector)
{
  int var_1 = ............ ;
  int var_2 = ............ ;

  return var_[selector];
}
```

The last line is equivalent to the code:

```
if (selector == 1)
{
  return var_1;
}
else if (selector == 2)
{
  return var_2;
}
```

But I need to evaluate the variable name during run-time using another variable (`selector`).
How to achieve this ? Also, what about the C language ?

I usually use the MATLAB command `eval` to do so.
Also, in C#, this can be achieved via Reflection.

Comment: Why not storing everything in an array in the first place? Maybe you could elaborate on what you want to achieve in the end. This sounds like a X-Y problem.

Comment: @MatthiasB: An X-Y problem almost always has a practical problem in the real world at its root. The 5 tags hint at an theoretical problem, so not X-Y.

Comment: So the question is specifically and only about the option to have something like `var_XX`, where `XX` is a runtime variable?

Comment: Then No, this is not possible in plain C++.

Comment: @HeshamEraqi Since c++ is a strongly typed and linked language, the evaluation of symbols at runtime isn't possible.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ : the conclusion is right, but it doesn't follow from the flawed assumption. A strongly typed language can still have introspection capability, but introspection might return "there's no variable of that name **and type**".

Comment: What are the possible values of `selector`? If they are contiguous (or only have little gaps in between), why not use an array?

Comment: @mafso: or `std::map`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ and C are both compiled languages. Variable names do not exist at runtime. This makes your idea entirely impossible.

C# is compiled, but there is a limited degee of reflection. *Type* names are available, but I don't think *variable* names are. So you're out of luck for basically the same reason.

MATLAB is interpreted, so there's no distinction between compile time and run time, and it does therefore have variable names available. The price is that MATLAB is slow.

Comment: Excellent answer. You got what I mean. Thank you. Do you have any evidence that we can't do so in C++ using some work-around's ?

Comment: @HeshamEraqi: Well, there's the obvious workaround that you already posted.

Answer (score 2):

```
int sampleFunction (int selector)
{
    int var_[] = {1, 2};

    return var_[selector];
}
```

Where 1 and 2 are the values of `var_1` and `var_2` respectively.

Comment: I don't know about C++, but declaring the array `static` is beneficial in C.

Comment: @downhillFromHere: And generally wrong. And only beneficial on old compilers.

Comment: Thank you. But you have misunderstood my question. My first piece of code is just a Pseudo-Code. `var_[selector]` is not an array.

Comment: and you get out of bound access with given example as `selector` is `1` or `2` (and not `0` or `1`).